# construct complex queries with WP User Query

Tags: wp-query, array, wp-user-query

Is it possible to create complex query with WP User Query ?

With WP Meta Query, we can make complex queries with Nested arrays like :

```
$meta_query_args = array(
    'relation' => 'OR', // Optional, defaults to "AND"
    array(
        'key'     => '_my_custom_key',
        'value'   => 'Value I am looking for',
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => '_my_custom_key_2',
            'value'   => 'Value I am looking for 2',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_my_custom_key_3',
            'value'   => 'Value I am looking for 3',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);
$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );
```

I’m not sure it is possible with :

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query($meta_query_args);
```

I don’t see in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) if it is possible.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

Here is my actual array and it is not working :

```
Array
(
    [relation] => AND
    [0] => Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fields] => ID
                    [key] => ville
                    [value] => INDRE
                    [compare] => LIKE
                    [type] => CHAR
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fields] => ID
                    [key] => user_metiers
                    [value] => 297
                    [compare] => LIKE
                    [type] => CHAR
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [relation] => OR
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fields] => ID
                    [key] => last_name
                    [value] => david
                    [compare] => LIKE
                    [type] => CHAR
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fields] => ID
                    [key] => first_name
                    [value] => david
                    [compare] => LIKE
                    [type] => CHAR
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $meta_query_args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR', // Optional, defaults to "AND"
    array(
        'key'     => '_my_custom_key',
        'value'   => 'Value I am looking for',
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => '_my_custom_key_2',
            'value'   => 'Value I am looking for 2',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_my_custom_key_3',
            'value'   => 'Value I am looking for 3',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )

);
$meta_query = new WP_User_Query( $meta_query_args );
```

add 'meta_query' => array(..)

Comment: Yes, it is working.